# HttpWebRequest SSL Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl

How login to the resource with SSL? I sent data with help HttpWebRequest on url. In half of cases return redirect to login page and dont't get cookies.

Maybe, make request on 443 port? If yes, how this make with help HttpWebRequest?

```
        ServicePointManager
            .ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        const string root = @"https://****/";
        var loginUrl = string.Format(@"{0}csologin/login.jsf", root);

        var login = Settings.Default.PacerLogin;
        var pass = Settings.Default.PacerPassword;
        var postData =
            string.Format(
                @"login=login&login:loginName={0}&login:password={1}&login:clientCode=&login:j_idt139=&javax.faces.ViewState=stateless",
                 login, pass);

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginUrl);
        request.CookieContainer = this.cookieContainer;

        var ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] postBytes = ascii.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Proxy = null;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, pass);
        request = SetHeaders(request, loginUrl);
        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

        Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        postStream.Flush();
        postStream.Close();
```

And Headers

```
        request.UserAgent =
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36";

        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4");
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=0";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = allowRedirect;
        request.Connection =
        request.Referer = referer;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Comment: HttpWebRequest should automatically make https-URL requests on the correct port. I'd say you need to URI-encode the values you format into your post string, so you may have trouble with passwords that contain `&` say. But I think you need to inspect the responses you get and see what's going wrong, or compare the traffic to genuine traffic from the website in case you're missing session cookies, CSRF tokens, etc. In any case that site may be deliberately rejecting automated logins if they can detect them - you could always ask if they have an API to use instead?

Comment: @Rup No, they don't have API. I watched in Fiddler requests of browser and my app, they are identical.

Comment: @Rup. I encoded URI with help URLEncode of HttpUtils, in result turns a strange set symbols, which no decode in forms, e.g. in Fiddler